# OmniAuth Shibboleth strategy configuration not passed through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, shibboleth

I'm trying to make use of [omniauth-shibboleth](https://github.com/toyokazu/omniauth-shibboleth) strategy (with [rack-saml](https://github.com/toyokazu/rack-saml)).

My omniauth initializer looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shibboleth, {
    :info_fields => {
      :email => 'mail',
    },
    :extra_fields => [:cn, :sn, :schacHomeOrganization],
  }
end
```

Everything is successful up to the point where omniauth-shibboleth should set up `omniauth.auth` ENV variable, but this ends up partial.

Namely - it does detect `eduPersonPrincipalName` and passes it to `uid` filed correctly - I can see it.

**But** it fails to fill in `email`, and the extra parameters `cn, sn, schacHomeOrganization`.

I have verified that the `request.env` **does contain** all of the required attributes, so the problem is not at Shibboleth side.

For debugging, I hardcoded the options in Gem file `lib/omniauth/strategies/shibboleth.rb`:

```
  option :info_fields, {:email => 'mail'}
  option :extra_fields, [:cn, :sn, :schacHomeOrganization]
```

Then everything works.

So, there seems to be problem either with my *Omniauth* setup or with the way *omniauth-shibboleth* handles the options, so that my configuration does not end up merged with default values.

What am I doing wrong?

Versions:

```
omniauth - 1.1.1
omniauth-shibboleth - 1.0.8
rack-saml - 0.0.4

pow - 0.4.0
```

Comment: Have you tried not putting the additional options in a hash? provider :shibboleth, :info_fields => {:email => 'mail'}, :extra_fields => [:cn, :sn, :schacHomeOrganization]

Comment: Yes, I have, though Omniauth source indicates it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that **Devise** handles Omniauth initialization itself and while I **could** use `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` to toggle `:debug => true`, Devise overrode any other options I had set.

So the correct place to configure **Omniauth strategies** while using **Devise** is in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.omniauth :shibboleth, {:uid_field => 'eppn',
                     :info_fields => {:email => 'mail', :name => 'cn', :last_name => 'sn'},
                     :extra_fields => [:schacHomeOrganization]
              }
```

Previously I thought that that line only hints Devise which strategy is the default.